# FINAL variable holds two different values in Java

Tags: java, language-lawyer

I have two cases below.

## Case 1:

```java
class A{
    A(){
        System.out.println("A's Constructor");
        f();
    }
    void f() {System.out.println("A");}
}

class B extends A{
    B(){
        System.out.println("B's Constructor");
        f();
    }
    final String x = "B";
    void f() {System.out.println(x);}
}

public class JavaPOCSamples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }
}
```

## Case 2:

```java
class A{
    A(){
        System.out.println("A's Constructor");
        f();
    }
    void f() {System.out.println("A");}
}

class B extends A{
    B(){
        System.out.println("B's Constructor");
        f();
    }
    final String x = "B".trim();
    void f() {System.out.println(x);}
}

public class JavaPOCSamples {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }
}
```

The difference between case 1 and case 2 is that case 2 has `final String x = "B".trim()` in `class B` but case 1 has `final String x = "B"` in `class B`.

## The output of case 1:

```
A's Constructor
B // Note that a final variable X is "B"
B's Constructor
B // Note that a final variable X is still "B"
```

## The output of case 2:

```
A's Constructor
null // Note that a final variable X is null
B's Constructor
B // Note that a final variable X is changed to "B"
```

The question is regarding case 2 output: why does `final String x` hold two different values, one is `null` and another one is string "B"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice puzzle related to the fine details of Java's `final` field semantics, and instance creation semantics. Like any other field, a `final` field is initialised to a default value when the object is created ([JLS §4.12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)):

> Every variable in a program must have a value before its value is used:
>
> - Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10.2):

The `final` is merely a compile-time check to make sure that the field will be assigned a value exactly once, at the time the object is created. At runtime, the field still has its default initial value before it is assigned a new value. However, there is a special case for `final` variables of primitive types or of type `String`, whose initializer is a constant expression ([§4.12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)):

> A constant variable is a final variable of primitive type or type String that is initialized with a constant expression (§15.28). Whether a variable is a constant variable or not may have implications with respect to class initialization (§12.4.1), binary compatibility (§13.1, §13.4.9), and definite assignment (§16 (Definite Assignment)).

A *constant expression* is defined in ([§15.28](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)) to include literals (including `String` literals), such as `"B"`. The expression `"B".trim()` is a method invocation expression, so it is not a constant expression.

The remaining detail is that when an instance of `B` is created, the `B()` constructor implicitly invokes the superclass constructor `A()`, and this occurs before the rest of the `B()` constructor or any initializers in the subclass `B` are executed ([§12.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5), emphasis mine):

> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure: ...
>
> 2. This constructor does not begin with an explicit constructor invocation of another constructor in the same class (using this). If this constructor is for a class other than Object, then **this constructor will begin with an explicit or implicit invocation of a superclass constructor (using super)**. ...
> 3. **Execute the instance initializers and instance variable initializers for this class**, assigning the values of instance variable initializers to the corresponding instance variables, in the left-to-right order in which they appear textually in the source code for the class.

So in case 2, because the assignment `x = "B".trim()` is in the subclass `B`, it is not executed until after the `A()` constructor has completed. Since the `A()` constructor calls `f()`, that method prints out a `null` value because that's the default value of the field before it has been assigned any other value.

However, in case 1, the special rule for a `final` field of type `String` initialized with a constant expression applies, so `x` is already `"B"` before the `A()` constructor is called.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, variable initialization will happen (except for all method invocation) before the class construction. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "class construction".

Comment: I meant to say that before the object creation

Comment: It happens during object creation, but after the superclass constructor is called.

Comment: but constant expression will be evaluated and initialised before the superclass constructor is called. Right??. Also, since B.trim() is a method invocation expression it will be evaluated and initialised only after superclass constructor is called.Right??

Comment: Since the evaluation of a constant expression can never have side-effects, the order of evaluation doesn't strictly matter; the rule is that a constant variable can never be observed to have its default initial value, even by "devious programs" (in the JLS's words).

Comment: Trying to understand - “constant variable can never be observed to have its default initial value”. Could you please elaborate with an example.

Comment: Well, the code in your question is an example - the variable `x` is a constant when its initializer is the string literal `"B"`, so it cannot be observed by the `f()` method to have its default initial value of `null`, even though `f()` is called before the fields of the class `B` are supposed to be initialized.

Comment: You mentioned that constant expression can never have side-effects. Are there any side-effects if I use a method invocation expression like "B".trim().? If yes then could you please explain it with a simple example.

Comment: The method `.trim()` has no side-effects, but the JLS rules for instance initialization don't treat non-constant expressions differently depending on whether they have side-effects or not. Actually, the Java compiler doesn't infer the side-effect-free-ness of methods at all.

Comment: You mentioned in your answer (last part) that Method invocation expression is not executed until after the A() constructor has completed. So I believe that compiler has a check internally whether initialiser is a constant expression or not.Right? If it is a non constant expression then initialisation will happen only after super class construction. Right ??

Comment: As noted in my answer, the JLS has a special rule for `final` fields initialised by constant expressions, so yes, the compiler has to check for that in order to have the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

`final` should always contain a `value`, not an object level computation unless the `state` is established.

You can set `final int x = 2 + 2`. It would work, but invoking a method needs state and `B` **does not** have that yet.

You can verify this by moving `final int x = "B".trim()` in class `A`. It would work as `A` already has `state` when `f()` is invoked.

Comment: I should have been clear. invoking methods on an object.

Comment: what you mean by B does not have a state

Comment: By that I meant B is not fully constructed only after which the fields get initialized completely.